# Creating a wishlist widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building quite a large website using WooCommerce and their wishlists addon. What I'd like to do is add a widget to the sidebar that shows the customers wishlists when they are logged in. There doesn't seem to be anything available at the moment so I thought I'd build it myself....

In the actual wishlists plugin files I found shortcodes-init.php which I thought would be good as a starting point to create the widget, as it should check if the person is logged in and if so, display their wishlists. All I then had to do was create the actual widget.

I created a new file that I added to the wishlists plugin folder (because I know my custom file won't get overwritten), set up the widget and added the code found in the shortcodes to display wishlists.

This is what I have:

```
// Creating the widget 
class wl_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct(
        // Base ID of your widget
        'wl_widget', 

        // Widget name will appear in UI
        __('Boards Widget', 'wl_widget_domain'), 

        // Widget description
        array( 'description' => __( 'Widget to add show customers boards', 'wl_widget_domain' ), ) );

    }

    // Creating widget front-end
    // This is where the action happens
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

        // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; 

        //We need to force WooCommerce to set the session cookie
        if ( !is_admin() && !WC_Wishlist_Compatibility::WC()->session->has_session() ) {
            WC_Wishlist_Compatibility::WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
        }


        ob_start();

        if (is_user_logged_in() || (WC_Wishlists_Settings::get_setting('wc_wishlist_guest_enabled', 'enabled') == 'enabled')) {
            //woocommerce_wishlists_get_template('my-lists.php');
            echo "loggedin";
        } else {
            //woocommerce_wishlists_get_template('guest-disabled.php');
            echo "loggedout";
        }

        return ob_get_clean();


        echo $args['after_widget'];

    }

    // Widget Backend 
    public function form( $instance ) {

        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'wl_widget_domain' );
        }

        // Widget admin form
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
        This widget automatically displays boards when the person is logged in so there is no further settings needed.
        </p>

        <?php 
    }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }

} // Class btn_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function wl_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'wl_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wl_load_widget' );
```

The problem I have is that this does not see if the customer is logged in or not and actually breaks the page. This is the code that seems to be the problem.

```
//We need to force WooCommerce to set the session cookie
        if ( !is_admin() && !WC_Wishlist_Compatibility::WC()->session->has_session() ) {
            WC_Wishlist_Compatibility::WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
        }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or another way to get the customers wishlists?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you get any error that tells you what is breaking? (don't forget to activate debug mode by changing WP_DEBUG constant to true in _wp-config.php_)

Comment: Hey vard, I don't get an error even with that active. Something in my hosting will not allow errors to display and they won't let me override it

Comment: Even with WP_DEBUG set to true?

Comment: 1. That's crappy hosting if it won't display errors even with `WP_DEBUG` 2. Instead of adding the file in Wishlists, I'd recommend a new plugin 3. what does "breaks the page" mean specifically... white screen of death? That could be something as simple as a typo. You really need debug mode. Try setting up a dev site somewhere locally or at a cloud hosting site such as c9.io.

Comment: Hi helgatheviking, thanks for commenting. I'm aware the hosting isn't great but there is a reason for it. Breaking the page means white screen. Can we move on from my lack of debugging tho pls? I've isolated the code thats the problem and highlighted it here. I don't think it is a typo as it came directly from the wishlists plugin.

Comment: We can't really move on from lack of debugging as debugging will likely tell us exactly what the error is. Your code doesn't display any of the Wishlists callbacks such as `shortcode_wc_wishlists_my_archive()` or `shortcode_wc_wishlists_single`. Why not use those to display the output in the widget?